# Scroll mouse position based function

Tags: jquery, scroll

Basically, I'm trying to have an "auto scroll" option for my site, I've got the basis of it working, although it doesn't re scroll back if you move the mouse back to the left rather than the right.

I've been at this for over 3 hours now, no luck what so ever searching the net!

Here's what I have:

```
 $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
    window.mouseYPos = e.pageY; 
       var height = $(window).height() /2;
       if (window.mouseYPos < height){
        $('body,html').stop().animate({     
            scrollTop: window.mouseYPos
        },10 );
       }
       else{
        $('body,html').stop().animate({     
            scrollTop: -window.mouseYPos
        },10 );
       }    
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delay your animation after 100ms where the mouse is not moving to avoid the new animation starts after each mouse pixel moving

```
scrollDelayTimer = null;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
       window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
       window.mouseYPos = e.pageY;

       clearTimeout(scrollDelayTimer);
       scrollDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
          scrollDelayTimer = null;
          $('body,html').stop().animate({
              scrollTop: window.mouseYPos,
              scrollLeft: window.mouseXPos
          },1000 );
       },100);
});
```

Comment: Hi Guys, It's not quite what I'm after, basically, to dumb it down, we can just work on the Y axis, but basically, I want to have it so that when the user scrolls positive past half way, it will auto scroll to the mouse position, and if the scroll back negative past half way it will do the reverse effect.. I edited my original code :) @bouillou

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that when the mouse moves to the left, it is moving off of the window, so it won't trigger the event.  You would want to scroll to a point where the mouse is inside the window.  Try

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
   window.mouseYPos = e.pageY;
   $('body,html').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: window.mouseYPos-$('window').height()/2,
    scrollLeft: window.mouseXPos-$('window').width()/2
   },1000 );
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do it :( It doesn't "subtract" the body position, it more or less only "adds to it": http://shannonhochkins.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/

Comment: On firefox, if I move my mouse up into the very top left of the page, it will scroll back.  Try using `$('window').height()/2` and `$('window').width()/2` instead of 30.  I also just pulled the little snippet of your code that did what I wanted to change -- you should add it back into the entire code.

Comment: I've added your changes to my site, but if you have a look, it doesn't actually scroll back up or back left, it just scrolls on the positive axis!
:(

Comment: I've not found a solution, the closest I have found is multiplying the Y value by 100 and dividing it by the document height then scrolling the position to the new number, this works brilliantly, but it's only defined to the "window" not the page. Can you take a quick look? 

`<code>

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  percent = ((e.pageY) * 100) / $(this).height(); 
  $('body').scrollTop( percent);   
 });

</code>`

See here! http://shannonhochkins.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/